# Nginx redirect to a url extracted from query string

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am trying to extract a url from a query parameter then redirect to that url using Nginx.

for example:
http://example.com/redirect/?url=www.google.com

to redirect to www.google.com

I have tried both return and rewrite, no luck so far.
Appreciate any help.

```
location /redirect/ {
        return 301 $arg_url;
        #this one appends example.com with the url. 

}

and ...

location /redirect/ {
        rewrite $arg_url last;
}
```

Comment: The [`query_string` variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_query_string) looks promising. The [`return` statement](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) seems to quite flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, the return statement works if using code 302 which is good enough. just need to make sure the url starts with http or https.

Comment: "`In addition, a URL for temporary redirect with the code 302 can be specified as the sole parameter. Such a parameter should start with the “http://”, “https://”, or “$scheme” string. A URL can contain variables.`"

Comment: `return 301 http://$arg_url;` works. If you need to test for presence of a scheme, you will need to use an `if (regex) { ... }` block.

Comment: Thanks Richard, yes that works. but as I am not sure if the url query string will start with (http, https or none) I think I have to use regex (ergghhh) as you suggested.